# Pull all numbers from a column in a DataGridView and write to a int list

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I'd like to retrieve all *numbers* (because there are other things in the column like "N/A" etc) in a column in my `DataGridView` and write them to a `List<int>`.

Some pseudocode:

```
List<int> data = new List<int>();
foreach (string s from column 3 in DataGridView)
{
   Check if s can be converted into a number;
   data.Add(Convert.ToInt32(s));
}
```

Comment: You can use `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
   {
       int result;
       if(int.TryParse((string)row.Cells[2].Value,out result)) data.Add(result);
   }
```

Comment: This triggers an `System.InvalidCastException`, System.Int32 cannot be converted to type System.String

Comment: Write `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString()` instead `(string)row.Cells[2].Value`

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the rows and get the value of the specific column. Use `int.TryParse` to attempt parsing the value into an `int`. If it fails, your loop will continue.

```
foreach(var item in DataGridView.Rows)
{
    int value;
    if(int.TryParse(item.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out value)) //Cells[2] is column #3
    {
        data.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the  rows of `DataGridView` and get the value of the desired column.

```
foreach(var row in DataGridView.Rows)
{  
  int value;
  if(int.TryParse(rows.Cells[2].Value.ToString(), out value))
  {
     yourList.Add(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an System.NullReferenceException when doing this. Is it because I wrapped it in a BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { } because it runs in a BackgroundWorker?